# Powershell. Why does the variable (Array) change?

Tags: powershell

Why is this happening. I have two arrays. The first is changed in a function, the second serves as a copy of the first array. But it doesn't work.
My code:

```
function testArray
{
   param
   (
       [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][array]$Board
   )

   $Board[1] = 'X'
   return $Board
}

[array]$test = @('.','.','.','.')
[array]$testCopy = $test

$test = testArray -Board $test

Write-Host $test
Write-Host $testCopy
```

Output:

. X . .

. X . .

Powershell Version: 5.1

Thanks

I have no idee why it happening.

Answer (score 3):

You should get familiar with `Value Types` and `Reference Types` see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)

Array is a reference type, which mean that when you set the `[array]$testCopy = $test` you are not creating a new Array but just add a new reference in the memory to the `$test` array,

so, if you change `$test`, `$testCopy` (which is just a reference) will show the value of `$test`

Comment: Oh, Thankes for you help.